# Python Flask Submit Button Not Working

Tags: python, html, css, forms, flask

I have two buttons on a page: follow and unfollow, the follow button is displayed if the user is not following a person and vice versa. I have the following code but for some reason only the unfollow button works. The follow button doesn't do anything - I click on it and nothing happens.

```
            if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.form['submit'] == 'Follow':
                c.execute("INSERT INTO users_followers(username,following) VALUES(?,?)",(session['username'],username,))
            elif request.form['submit'] == 'Unfollow':
                c.execute("DELETE FROM users_followers WHERE username = ? AND following = ?",(session['username'],username,))
            conn.commit()
            return redirect(url_for("profilepage",username=username))
```

HTML Code:

```
{%if profile[0][1] == current%}
{%else%}
{% if following == True %}
<form action="/profile/{{username}}" class="form" method="post">
    <input class="btn btn--sm type--uppercase" name="submit" style="background: #e74c3c;border-color: #c0392b;color:white;width:100px;" type="submit" value="Unfollow">
{%else%} 
    <input class="btn btn--sm type--uppercase" name="submit" style="background: #4a90e2;border-color: #4a90e2;color:white;width:100px;" type="submit" value="Follow">
{%endif%} 
<a class="btn btn--sm btn--primary-2 type--uppercase" href="#"><span class="btn__text">Send Message</span></a>
</form>
{%endif%}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not printing the form tag if `following` is not true. Move the following code out of the If statement.

```
<form action="/profile/{{username}}" class="form" method="post">
```

Comment: It was so obvious but I didn't even think about that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have "Follow3" assing to value instead of "Follow" change that value and it should work.

```
value="Follow"
```

Edit: add attribute code

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to change it back. It didn't work before that as well. I just changed it to follow3 to see if it would do anything

Comment: No problem, does it work without the execute command? I mean did you already tried to print something in that if and didn't work either right?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I put a print statement just before the sql execute but it doesn't print.

Comment: What I did was I put a print statement right after the first if statement as well. It only works with the unfollow button. When I click the follow button it doesn't seem to be posting the details

Comment: hmmm try to print the content of `request.form['submit']` and see what is in there (or the whole form), maybe that can help.